# How to update nested array in mongoDB using express

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to update nested array 'commentLikes' in mongodb using nodejs. I have tried like this but not helped.

My Collection is this

```
_id: 6368f9cd1d1ae931a66de06e
userId: "625400bc00575a0301756870"
desc: "helloooooooo..."
location: ""
taggedFriends: Array
edited: false
likes: Array
dislikes: Array
comments: Array
   0: Object
   1: Object
      commentId: "0.9418743386578314"
      dp: "pic1.jpg"
      name: "Mohammad Ashraf"
      id: "625400bc00575a0301756870"
      comment: "avvdvd jhuygjhgd"
      commentLikes: Array
      nestedComments: Array
```

and I want to update commentLikes, And I have try like one

```
//like comment
router.put("/:id/comment/:commentId/like", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
    const comment = await post.comments.find((cmnt)=>cmnt.commentId===req.params.commentId);
    if (!comment.commentLikes.includes(req.body.userId)) {
      // await comment.updateOne({$push: {commentLikes: req.body.userId}});
      await post.updateOne({"comments.commentId": req.params.commentId}, {$push: {"comments.$.commentLikes": req.body.userId}});
      res.status(200).json("The comment has been liked");
    } else {
      // await comment.updateOne({ $pull: { commentLikes: req.body.userId } });   // toggle
      res.status(200).json("like removed");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.postComments = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const comment = req.body;
  const blogId = req.params.blogId;
  if (
    !Object.keys(comment).length != 0 ||
    !Object.getPrototypeOf(comment) === Object.prototype ||
    !ObjectId.isValid(comment?.userId)
  ) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      response,
      success: false,
      message: "invalid request for comments",
    });
    // console.log("hello");
  }
  const response = await Blog.updateOne(
    { _id: blogId },
    {
      $push: { comments: comment },
    }
  );
  if (response.modifiedCount <= 0) {
    return res.status(200).json({
      response,
      success: false,
      message: "can not insert new comment please try again",
    });
  }
  res.status(200).json({
    response,
    success: false,
    message: "can not insert new comment please try again",
  });
  //   console.log(response);
});

or you can ask me for more question

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    exports.postComments = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
      const comment = req.body;
      const blogId = req.params.blogId;
      if (
        !Object.keys(comment).length != 0 ||
        !Object.getPrototypeOf(comment) === Object.prototype ||
        !ObjectId.isValid(comment?.userId)
      ) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          response,
          success: false,
          message: "invalid request for comments",
        });
        // console.log("hello");
      }
      const response = await Blog.updateOne(
        { _id: blogId },
        {
          $push: { comments: comment },
        }
      );
      if (response.modifiedCount <= 0) {
        return res.status(200).json({
          response,
          success: false,
          message: "can not insert new comment please try again",
        });
      }
      res.status(200).json({
        response,
        success: false,
        message: "can not insert new comment please try again",
      });enter code here
      //   console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.